# Find all positive integers $a, n$ such that $a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n=2001$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

All I have got so far is that $a$ must divide $2002$... Could anyone share some ideas? I mean is there any method rather than trial and error?

Comment: yep... that's what I have got so far as I said....

Comment: Already a nice observation! By a similar argument, one can show that $a+1$ must divide $2001 + (-1)^n$. You can also show that $a\equiv1\pmod3$ and that $n$ is even, by considering both sides modulo $3$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks a lot for the hint. However, I am still wondering why $n$ must be even and how to show that $a\cong 1 \mod 3$...

Comment: @GregMartin Oh nvm I got them lol. Thank you so much. BTW just one last question, how did you come up with the idea of considering both sides modulo 3?

Comment: just trying out the factors of 2001 (not that there are many)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At most one of $a,a+1$ is a multiple of $3$.

If exactly one of $a,a+1$ is a multiple of $3$, then
$$
a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n
$$
would not be a multiple of $3$, contradiction, since $2001$ is a multiple of $3$,

Thus neither of $a,a+1$ is a multiple of $3$, hence $a\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;3)$,

If $n$ is odd, then

\begin{align*}
&
a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n=2001
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n\equiv 2001\;(\text{mod}\;3)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
1^{n+1}-2^n\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
1-2\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)
\end{align*}
contradiction.

Hence $n$ is even.$\;$Then

\begin{align*}
&
a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n=2001
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n\equiv 2001\;(\text{mod}\;(a+1))
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(-1)^{n+1}-0^n\equiv 2001\;(\text{mod}\;(a+1))
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
-1\equiv 2001\;(\text{mod}\;(a+1))
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2002\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;(a+1))
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(a+1){\,\mid\,}2002
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

and as you noted, we also have $a{\,\mid\,}2002$, thus both $a$ and $a+1$ are divisors of $2002$.

Hence since $\gcd(a,a+1)=1$, it follows that $\bigl(a(a+1)\bigr){\,\mid\,}2002$.

Then $a(a+1)\le 2002$, so $a < 45$.

From the prime factorization of $2002=(2)(7)(11)(13)$, we get that the only positive integer divisors of $2002$ which are less than $45$ are $1,2,7,11,13,14,22,26$, and of those potential values of $a$, only $a=1$ and $a=13$ are such that $a+1$ is also a divisor of $2002$.

But if $a=1$, then $a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n=1-2^n < 0$, contradiction.

It remains to analyze the case $a=13$.

Suppose $13^{n+1}-14^n=2001$.

If $n > 2$, then

\begin{align*}
&
13^{n+1}-14^n=2001
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
13^{n+1}-14^n\equiv 2001\;(\text{mod}\;8)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
13^{n+1}\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;8)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(13^n)(13)\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;8)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(1)(5)\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;8)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

Hence since $n$ is even, the only remaining possibility is $n=2$.

By direct evaluation, it can be verified that $13^3-14^2=2001$.

Therefore $a=13, n=2$ is the only solution in positive integers to the given equation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but it's an idea on how you could further narrow down your options

You can try taking (mod a) of either side to get $-1\equiv2001($mod $a)$ (I'm assuming that's how you got a divides 2002).

Taking (mod 3) of either side shows that a isn't congruent to 0 or 2 (mod 3), so it must be congruent to 1 (mod 3), and n must be even.

Finally you can take the (mod a+1) of either side to get $-1^{n+1}\equiv 2001($mod $a+1) \Rightarrow (a+1)|2002$ since n is even.

This reduces the possible values of a to 1 and 13, and a=1 obviously won't have any solutions.